# SQL syntax in JAVA forms getText();

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Just looking for a little help,

Created an application in JAVA and using a jTable to gather data from myphp database, I am using Insert, update and delete SQL commands so the user is able to manipulate data in the table.

Delete works perfectly, however I am having some trouble with my update and insert commands, just wondering if anyone can see if im using the ("'+) incorrectly, im not as eagle eyed as someone more experienced so just seeing if anyone can shed some light :)

Thanks!

INSERT CODE :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `supplier`(`Company Name`, `Contact`, `Address`, `Postcode`, `Phone`) VALUES ('"+jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierContact.getText()+"',"+jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierPostcode.getText()+"',"+jTextField_SupplierPhone.getText()+")";
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
String query = "UPDATE `supplier` SET `Company Name`='"+jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText() + "',`Contact`='"+jTextField_SupplierContact.getText() + "',`Address`="+jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText() + "',`Postcode`="+jTextField_SupplierPostcode.getText() + "',`Phone`="+jTextField_SupplierPhone.getText() + " WHERE `ID` = "+jTextField_SupplierID.getText();
```

ERROR:

The error is throwing is the misuse of the WHERE clause in the "UPDATE" statement... May be obvious to some however cant get my head around it.

Comment: Please learn to use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid these type of syntax errors, or any SQL Injection, you can use PreparedStatement instead, it is so simple and so helful :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `supplier`(`Company Name`, `Contact`, `Address`, `Postcode`, `Phone`) "
    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    pstm.setString(1, jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText());
    pstm.setString(2, jTextField_SupplierContact.getText());
    pstm.setString(3, jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText());
    pstm.setString(4, jTextField_SupplierPostcode.getText());
    pstm.setString(5, jTextField_SupplierPhone.getText());

    pstm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Your error happen because you forgot to close your String with `''` check your query and you will see :

```
+"', " + jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText() + "'
//--^--------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: I spoke to soon, 
NO idea what I have just done, its throwing an error, 
Can i just confirm something, the (Query) in my case would be ("INSERT INTO ?, ?, VALUES (jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText(), ?, ?,  )

I have no idea why, it updates two fields in the db, but no more :/

Comment: Makes so much more sense!! That DOES work! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You Missed the Single quote in query

**use this for insert**

String query = "INSERT INTO `supplier`(`Company Name`, `Contact`, `Address`, `Postcode`, `Phone`) VALUES ('"+jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierContact.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierPostcode.getText()+"','"+jTextField_SupplierPhone.getText()+"')";

**Use this for update**

String query = "UPDATE 'supplier' SET 'Company Name`='"+jTextField_SupplierCompany.getText() + "',`Contact`='"+jTextField_SupplierContact.getText() + "',`Address`='"+jTextField_SupplierAddress.getText() + "',`Postcode`='"+jTextField_SupplierPostcode.getText() + "',`Phone`='"+jTextField_SupplierPhone.getText() + "' WHERE`ID` = '"+jTextField_SupplierID.getText()+"'";

Comment: -1 for an answer that still leaves the user open to SQL injection, and for not even bothering to format your post correctly.

Comment: Exactly! If you know that, then why not base your answer on that, instead of answering with a minor fix that leaves open a gaping security hole.